# How to fix 'IndentationError: expected an indented block' in python

Tags: python-3.x

i found IndentationError

> IndentationError: expected an indented block on line 33  at auditday =
>   week2['calendar.MONDAY']

here is code , error is on second last line, i am using latest python3.7 version

```
# The calendar can give info based on local such a names of days and months (full and abbreviated forms)
for name in calendar.month_name:
    print(name)
for day in calendar.day_name:
    print(day)
# calculate days based on a rule: For instance an audit day on the second Monday of every month
# Figure out what days that would be for each month, we can use the script as shown here
for month in range(1, 13):
    # It retrieves a list of weeks that represent the month
    mycal = calendar.monthcalendar(2025, month)
    # The first MONDAY has to be within the first two weeks
    week1 = mycal[1]
    week2 = mycal[2]
    if week1[calendar.MONDAY] != 0:
        auditday = week1['calendar.MONDAY']
    else:
    # if the first MONDAY isn't in the first week, it must be in the second week
    auditday = week2['calendar.MONDAY']
print("%10s %2d" % (calendar.month_name[month], auditday))
```

Comment: As python is so helpfully pointing out - indent the line - it should align with line 30 (the one after the `if` statement)

Comment: You need to correct the indention of the last statement after `else`, check my answer below!

Answer (score 1):

Like the if loop, else loop should also be indented four spaces.

```
if week1[calendar.MONDAY] != 0:
    auditday = week1['calendar.MONDAY']
else:
# if the first MONDAY isn't in the first week, it must be in the second week
    auditday = week2['calendar.MONDAY']
```

Thanks

Comment: You may want to reword your answer - loop is probably not the right word to describe conditional statements

Answer (score 0):

You missed an indentation block in the last else.

```
else:
    # if the first MONDAY isn't in the first week, it must be in the second week
    auditday = week2['calendar.MONDAY']
```

So the entire code will look like.

```
for name in calendar.month_name:
    print(name)
for day in calendar.day_name:
    print(day)
# calculate days based on a rule: For instance an audit day on the second Monday of every month
# Figure out what days that would be for each month, we can use the script as shown here
for month in range(1, 13):
    # It retrieves a list of weeks that represent the month
    mycal = calendar.monthcalendar(2025, month)
    # The first MONDAY has to be within the first two weeks
    week1 = mycal[1]
    week2 = mycal[2]
    if week1[calendar.MONDAY] != 0:
        auditday = week1['calendar.MONDAY']
    else:
    # if the first MONDAY isn't in the first week, it must be in the second week
        auditday = week2['calendar.MONDAY']
print("%10s %2d" % (calendar.month_name[month], auditday))
```

From next time onwards, try to use an IDE for Python like PyCharm, which will highlight the syntax where you get Indentation errors